# Gradle task ":app:dexBuilderDebug" fails with AccessDeniedException (Android Studio can't delete directories)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I'm using Android Studio Arctic Fox (2020.3.1 Patch 3 | Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7784292, built on October 1, 2021). When I try to build my project, gradle task ":app:dexBuilderDebug" fails throwing AccessDeniedException. For a short time, the problem is solved only by manually deleting these directories. **So how can I make Android Studio be able to delete these directories automatically again?** (running as administrator didn't help). Thanks

**Full exception message:**

```
Execution failed for task ':app:dexBuilderDebug'.
> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\Roman\AndroidDevelopment\AndroidProjects\Project\app\build\intermediates\desugar_graph\debug\out\currentProject\dirs_bucket_0
```

Comment: I decided to back up a project using google drive, was curious how it'd behave when using Home PC/Work laptop, and ever since I did that I'm having this error pop up every 2/3 builds, mostly when I change the device I'm testing on, so just in case: Did you back up your folder(s)/project(s) to google drive maybe?

Comment: Also, can't edit the comment now so I'm making another one: I don't manually delete the directory - I use 'Clean project' instead of that, still an extra step but better than searching for the file imo

Comment: @CoffeeCode Yes! I tried to back up a project using google drive too

Comment: Almost forgot about this - I can confirm that when you remove the project from google drive everything goes back to normal; I guess we should stick to VCS-only :P

Comment: Oh yes, it seems to me that we need to synchronize projects only through VCS, they do an excellent job with their work. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that the project folder was syncing with Google Drive. One had only to remove it from the synchronized ones, and everything worked out right away. My advice is to use VCS, their functionality will certainly be enough

Comment: Thanks! for others, after you move the project folder away from Google Drive Syncing area, go to Project->app->build and manually delete build folder. than re-run build and it works, at least for me.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to the dirs_bucket_0 error is just to hit Build -> Clean Project, then Build -> Rebuild Project. This got rid of the error and I was then able to run the app on my device while keeping everything synced on Google Drive.

Answer (score 0):

My situation was the same with the post. But as the only one answer, it's not suitable for me. My solution is to delete all of the files in the folder that the android studio IDE command told you in the wrong place. Then, you build the code again, it works.

Comment: It really works, but unfortunately, after a while, the error repeats and you have to delete the folders again